# Structs & code interpretations

Tags: c, pointers, struct, printf, naming

I'm studying for a midterm, and I'm having trouble following this program.

In the `int main (void)`, the first `printf` should print `Jello,3.14159`
I follow how it prints the `Jello,3.14` but not the 159 - where does `u.q.a` point to?

```
/* 01234567890:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct R {
    char n[6];
    int a;
};

struct S {
    double p;
    struct R q;
};

struct S f(const struct R* x) {
    struct S a;
    a.q = *x;
    a.p = 3.142;
    return a;
}

char g(struct R* y) {
    strcpy_s(y->n, "Wee");
    y->a = 3;
    return *y->n;
}

int main(void) {
    char c;
    struct S u;
    struct R x = { "Jello", 159 };
    u = f(&x);
    printf("%s,%.2lf%d\n", u.q.n, u.p, u.q.a);
    c = g(&x);
    printf("%s,%d.142,%cee\n", x.n, x.a, c);
    x.n[0] -= 3;
    x.n[1] = 'r';
    printf("%seeeeeeeeee\n", x.n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to tag this C, not C++? (I hope so!)

Comment: Do they really teach you C++ that looks like this? How unfortunate.

Comment: `u.q.a` holds a copy of `x.a`, which in turn was initialized to 159

Comment: `struct R x = { "Jello", 159 };` the 159 is put into `int a;`in `struct r?`

Comment: Yes. What else do you think it could be doing? Read about aggregate initialization in your favorite C or C++ textbook.

Comment: can you add output of this program?

Comment: When deciphering code with bad variable names, it often helps to rename variables and types (preferably using an IDE which can rename in C, but case-sensitive whole-word search replace works too).

Comment: Do I have a complete answer here?

Comment: Andrew, welcome to Stackoverflow, interesting question (+1) and if I have managed to completely answer for you, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it, and it will give you +2 to your rep. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

> the first printf should print "Jello,3.14159" i follow how it prints
>   the Jello,3.14 but not the 159...

and

> where does " u.q.a" point to?

Are both answered together. Here is the relevant output:

```
3.14159
```

Which comes from the printf format: `%.2lf%d`. The `3.14` comes from the first part of the specification, `%.2lf`, which says, expecting a long float, to show the number at 2 digits of precision. See wikipedia for more on `printf` formatting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string

The `159` comes from `u.q.a` (which is what it points to), and is brought into the formatting by the `%d` at the end of the specification. It was originally given to the `R` struct, which has the `int` `a`. and it becomes the `q` part of the `S` struct, `f`.

Answer (score 0):

`u.q.a` gets the value of the integer `a` from `x`(of type `struct R`). In fact, `u.q.a` is the same as `x.a` as pointer `q` in `u`(of type `struct S`) points to the address of `x`.
Since the value of `a` in `x` is set to 159, it gets printed from the last `%d` of the first `printf`.

PS: Please use meaningful names for variables in order to avoid confusing and make the code more easier and faster to read.